# Shingles in Elasticsearch, why does this example with custom analyzer fail?

Tags: elasticsearch

I rephrased my problem into a full curl recreation script. That way it might be easier to reproduce the problem (search fails with custom analyzer). I am using the latest ES version for this

## Remove old data

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling"
```

## Create index with settings

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/" -d '{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 10,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ShingleAnalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "BreadcrumbPatternAnalyzer",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "filter_stemmer",
            "filter_shingle"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "filter_shingle": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "max_shingle_size": 2,
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "output_unigrams": false
        },
        "filter_stemmer": {
          "type": "porter_stem",
          "language": "English"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "BreadcrumbPatternAnalyzer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": " |\\$\\$\\$"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

## Define mapping

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_mapping" -d '{
  "item": {
    "properties": {
      "Title": {
        "type": "string",
        "search_analyzer": "ShingleAnalyzer",
        "index_analyzer": "ShingleAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

## Create Document

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/" -d '{
  "Title":"Kyocera Solar Panel Test"
}'
```

## Test Analyzer PASS

```
curl 'localhost:9200/test_shingling/_analyze?pretty=1&analyzer=ShingleAnalyzer' -d 'Kyocera Solar Panel Test'
```

## Wait for ES to be synced (aka refresh indices)

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/_refresh"
```

## Search "Kyocera Solar Panel Test" FAIL

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Title": "Kyocera Solar Panel Test"
    }
  }
}'
```

## Search "Solar Panel" FAIL

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Title": "Kyocera Solar Panel Test"
    }
  }
}'
```

## Search "Kyocera Solar Panel Test" FAIL

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "Title",
      "query": "Kyocera Solar Panel Test"
    }
  }
}'
```

## Search "Solar Panel" FAIL

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "Title",
      "query": "solar panel"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: may i know why you stick with query string query??  and reason for using BreadcrumbPatternAnalyzer ??

Comment: BreadcrumbPatternAnalyzer is used in another analyzer to analyze a breadcrumb.. it is sort of a legacy from the more detailed production mapping. I did't understand the first part of your question!

Comment: try this : curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {"term": {
       "Title": {
          "value": "solar panel"
       }
    }}
}'

Comment: works. but this doesn't: curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search" -d' { "query": {"term": { "Title": { "value": "Kyocera Solar Panel Test" } }} }'. I am irritated. Shouldn't the search query be analyzed by ShingleAnalyzer and then the returned terms are compared? This should return a match from my understanding.

Comment: the BreadcrumbPatternAnalyzer splits the tokens in to two words. So it will find the only token you see in analyzed words..Do a thing .. post your exact requirement.. i ll try to post the answer and say why you going for BreadcrumbPatternAnalyzer??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term query will search for an exact match and won't apply ShingleAnalyzer to your query.

So you have to use the match query, this will apply the Analyzer to your query string when searching.

**Whole word search**

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search" -d'{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "Title": "Kyocera Solar Panel Test"
        }
    }
}'
```

**Partial Word search**

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search" -d'{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "Title": "Panel Test"
        }
    }
}'
```

**Another Partial word search**

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_shingling/item/_search" -d'{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "Title": "Solar Panel Test"
        }
    }
}'
```

Hope it helps..!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the search `query_string` considers `solar panel` as `solar` or `panel` by default and that you have to set it explicitly in the `query_string`. This is what's written in the [reference guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

> default_operator :
>
> The **default operator** used if no explicit operator is specified. For example, with a default operator of OR, the query capital of Hungary is translated to capital OR of OR Hungary, and with default operator of AND, the same query is translated to capital AND of AND Hungary. The default value is OR.

Comment: can you suggest a query that I can try?

Comment: {
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
                    "default_operator": "and" ,"default_field": "Title",
            "query": "solar panel"
        }
    }
}

Comment: It is the same as the one that you used for your example but I have just set the default_operator to "and" instead of "or"

Comment: sorry. it doesn't work. please note that in the mapping configuration for the field "Title" a default search_analyzer is defined which should actually take all input queries and create shingle terms from it.. so a query like "manufacturer solar panel abc" will be split into terms "manufacturer solar", "solar panel", "panel abc" by the analyzer